# React App Crashes When Deployed to Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I just deployed my React app to Heroku and while the deployment was successful, the ap crashes and I get an Application Error on the screen. I ran Heroku Logs and it returned this error:

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=quoriron-
client-app.herokuapp.com request_id=fe82d878-75ce-47b2-a726-
513725e679f2 fwd="65.209.61.114" dyno= connect= service= status=503 
bytes= protocol=https
```

Other people have had that error with Node apps and it's seems to usually be an issue with setting the port, but from my understanding the port isn't set the same way in React (or if that's even the problem).

How can I prevent my React app from crashing because of this error?

Comment: Why u deployed app on heroku ? BIG QUESTION. You can directly install app on your device. And may be for further server communication, you can use API(written in node), deploy on heroku, and then consume them.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean. It was my understanding that the Rails backend and the React frontend both had to be deployed to Heroku in order for them to function.

Comment: There is no requirement for putting apk anywhere. You can simply generate apk and install on your device. As far as consuming API is concerned(either written in node or rails), you can deploy those on any cloud based service(for eg Heroku), and consume them in you application.

Comment: yeah, that's what i've done. my issue is with getting the react app to show up after its deployed.

Comment: You mean you have deployed the rails on heroku, not the apk. Right ?

Comment: rails is functioning as the API and that's been deployed. the React Ap is deployed but it's not rendering properly because the error.

Comment: As i said, no need for deploying the apk. Just install on your physical device or run on android emulator.

Comment: this isn't React-Native or Android. It's a website.

Answer (score 0):

First sorry for reply this as an answer while it should be a comment...

How did you deploy the React app to Heroku?? Did you use their zero configuration for React apps or did you created your own Node.js that serve the react app?

Also you'll need to add the correctly buildpack to the project.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It has a Rails backend, so I deployed that first. I thought it was possible to deploy a React app directly, so I was trying to do that now and ended up with this error. Is there a different process I have to take for a react app in this case?

Comment: I think the buildpack is okay, because usually the deploy won't go through if there's an issue with it.

Comment: Did you used create-react-app for creating your app? If that's the case, just paste `https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git` into your buildpacks settings... It'll configure everything for you and make your app works